# Working with multiple categories group, show not empty from only one category group

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories, category-group

I am having trouble showing a list of **map** categories that are not empty but they must work in conjunction with the **countries** category group

No children categories needed

---

My categories setup

- Map group

  - Topographic
  - Geophysical
  - Geology

---

- Countries group

  - Kenya
  - South Africa
  - Tanzania

---

**Eg:**

- Entry one - Kenya & Geology
- Entry two - Kenya & Geology
- Entry three - Kenya & Geophysical

---

My result should be on this address

url: `/maps/category/kenya`

- Geophysical
- Geology

---

Any ideas, no luck with native categories and Gwcode categories tags. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving my solution here

I have used [low2seg](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) plugin and query. Little messy but it works.

`` {exp:query sql="select * from exp_categories as ec where ec.`cat_id` in (select distinct cat_id from `exp_category_posts` where entry_id in (select entry_id from `exp_category_posts` where cat_id = {segment_3_category_id})) and group_id = 1"}
<option value="{cat_id}">{cat_name}</option>
{/exp:query} ``

---

At the end of the query, ensure you choose selected cat_id and group_id

`where cat_id = {segment_3_category_id})) and group_id = 1"`